# Convergence theorems for improper integrals

Tags: reference-request, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, limsup-and-liminf

For a sequence of $\mathbb{R}$-valued (Borel-)measurable functions $\{h_n\}_{n=1,2,\cdots}$ let us consider
$$
\int_0^1\frac{h_n(x)}{1-x}dx:=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{h_n(x)}{1-x}dx.
$$
Here we regard the integral in the right-hand side as Lebesgue integral.
Assume that the limit exists for each $n=1,2,\cdots$.
Then is the assumptions of Fatou's lemma enough to establish
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{h_n(x)}{1-x}dx\ge\int_0^1\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{h_n(x)}{1-x}dx?
$$

I'm confused to answer this question because I have to change the order $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}$.
However, in this case, it's not always that $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}$ or $\liminf_{n\to\infty}$ have any uniformity (such as Moore-Osgood Theorem).
I don't know whether well-known convergence theorems are valid for improper integrals or not.

Please tell me ideas, answers or references if you have.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, that' right.  My integral doesn't always converge because of the denominator and I don't have any assumptions on $h_n$ to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you. But I have tried it and realized that I have to change the order of limitations to do so. As I wrote, there is no assumption of uniformly convergence, so I'm confused.

Comment: I'm sorry that my understanding is bad. I know that you are saying but it is leading me to an idea to show my desired inequality. Could you explain more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\{h_n\}$ to be positive measurable functions (otherwise you can't use Fatou's lemma), then 
\begin{align}
f_n(x) = \frac{h_n(x)}{1-x}
\end{align}
is also a sequence of positive measurable functions. Hence it follows 
\begin{align}
f(x):= \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{h_n(x)}{1-x}
\end{align}
is also measurable. Then by Fatou's lemma, we have that 
\begin{align}
\int^1_0 f(x)\ dx \leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \int^1_0 f_n(x)\ dx.
\end{align}
This inequality allows for both left and right side to be infinity.